# Scrollify get each page to animate it

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-scrollify

I have to work with the library Scrollify.js which is using jQuery (unfortunately). I need to add `class` on some `div` when scrolling on a specific section. I'm trying to get each page in terms of animate `divs`.

Right know I have an event before and after scrolling on all section but need to be independant/specific on each the section.
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/0kqybuf2/) demo

```
$(function() {
  $.scrollify({
    section: ".panel",
    before: function(nextIndex, elements) {
//      alert('before event was sent');
    },
    after: function(index) {
//      alert('after is triggered here');
    }
  });

  $(".scroll,.scroll-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.scrollify.next();
  });
});
```

From the github's author, it [looks like this](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/examples/apple/) but confused me...

```
 before: function(i,panels) {
            var ref = panels[i].attr("data-section-name");


            panels[i].find(".gallery0,.gallery1,.gallery2").addClass("moved");


            if(ref==="design") {
                $(".features").find(".gallery0,.gallery1,.gallery2").removeClass("moved");
                $(".ios7 .gallery0").css("top",0);
            }
            if(ref==="features") {
                $(".ios7 .content").removeClass("moved");
                initialPosition();
            }
            if(ref==="ios7") {
                $(".ios7 .content").addClass("moved");

                $(".ios7 .gallery0").css("top",0);
            }
        },
        after:function(i,panels) {
            var ref = panels[i].attr("data-section-name");

            if(ref==="home") {
                $(".design").find(".gallery0,.gallery1,.gallery2").removeClass("moved");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are you aiming at ?

Comment: I want to add a 'class' on a div when I'm scrolling on a section. Right know it can but on all sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `$.scrollify.current()` to select the current scrolled section and add class to it

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kqybuf2/4/)**

```
if($.scrollify.current().attr('data-section-name')=="configuration")
{
   $.scrollify.current().addClass('config');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Can the class be added in a div inside "config" and ten removed when going to another section ?

Comment: Yes after selecting the current object you can do anything with it.. add /remove class or anything

Comment: In your JSFiddle, it add the class "config" when going on it. But how would you remove it when leaving it ?

Comment: @Leshautsdurant : You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/0kqybuf2/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yo Yo !  I get it now !